# Can I use dd to quickly resilver a ZFS mirror disk?

Tags: dd, zfs

My ZFS pool consists of two mirrored disks.  I have two more disks which I plan to use for rotating offsite backups.  The first backup disk was added to the zpool and has nearly completed resilvering.

My question is: if I remove the resilvered backup disk from the machine can I `dd` it to the second backup disk, and have the resulting disk work as-expected when it's added back into the pool during its rotation?  `dd` would be quite a bit faster than resilvering which is the main reason I'm thinking of doing it (the pool is nearly full and contains a large number of small files).

Comment: `dd` would only be significantly faster if the pool was almost full as re-silvering with ZFS arrays only writes the used blocks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I forgot to mention that is indeed the case in my situation, presently the pool is about 90% full.  It also contains a lot of very small files which result in a slower resilvering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use dd and have any semblance of safety for your data.

If you're running Oracle Solaris, then you can use the 'zpool split' command.
Please see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36835/gjooc.html for details